# Dynamically bind matSuffix and matPrefix based on condition angular material 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular9, angular-template

How can I dynamically bind matSuffix and matPrefix on mat-icon in angular 9 material design?

I didn't like the way I did. Is their any better way to do it?

```
<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock"><mat-icon matSuffix>visibility_off</maticon></div>
<ng-template #elseBlock><mat-icon matPrefix>visibility_off</maticon></ng-template>
```

I want to do something like this

```
<mat-icon [matPrefix/matSuffix] --> some condition>{{icon}}</mat-icon>
```

Based on the condition it should add matPrefix or matSuffix

Comment: I don't think that is possible. As far as I know, you cannot dynamically apply directives in Angular. You can create your own directive or you can manipulate your icons behaviour through JavaScript but you end up with unnecessary code complexity. In my opinion, your solution is pretty clean and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

`<div [attr.matPrefix]="condition" [attr.matSuffix]="condition">`

Note: When condition is `null` the attribute is removed